# How to create a root file

Tags: root-framework

I am a beginner in root and I wanna to create a root file but in the first step I have an error. When I wanna to define TFile, I have this error massage : incomplete type is not allowed.
What is wrong?

```
TFile* F = new TFile("test.root", NEW);
```

Comment: Do you use `ROOT 6`? If so, try running the following in your shell: `root -l -b -q -e "TFile* F = new TFile(\"test.root\", \"NEW\")"` - did a `test.root` appear? If not, what was the exact error message?

Comment: No, the root version that I am using is not root 6. I use 5 version.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of the TFile constructor you're using is a string ([link to doc](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTFile.html#ad0377adf2f3d88da1a1f77256a140d60)). In what you wrote, the compiler frontend (be it a normal compiler application that you're using directly, or a dispatched compilation from the root command line, or cling as a jit compiler frontend), `NEW` is just a bare unknown word.

The correct version would be

```cpp
TFile* file = new TFile("test.root", "NEW");
```

(or my suggestion

```cpp
TFile* file = TFile::Open("test.root", "NEW");
```

because `Open` allows [other filenames](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTFile.html#ad8870806a04da2c2f4aa02bee4ec6833) that are on a network, should you ever need that. and you might also prefer [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of a bare pointer such that your file gets closed automatically as the pointer goes out of scope

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<TFile> file{TFile::Open("file.root", "NEW")};
```

… though I'm not sure the latter works well with all usage patterns and tutorials out there on the internet that …
)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put NEW in " " ! But it isn't the problem. The error exist yet. I have an error with TFile.

Comment: then the code you posted is probably not the problem. What are you doing with that line: a) type it as-is into the root prompt b) have it in a file that you load from the root prompt with '.L file.C' (or .x) without a '+' sign c) have it in a file and load it with `.L file.C+` (or .x) with a `+` sign appended to the filename d) in a c++ source code file in a "normal" c++ project in which you include the root headers and that you link against the root libs. Also please post the complete error message. I suspect you do c) or d) and forgot `#include "TFile.h"` in your file.

Comment: Thank you, the problem solved. I didn't know TFile has library.